# Google Apps Script GmailApp from Web Page

Tags: angular, google-apps-script, web-applications, cors, http-get

I am trying to access Google Apps Script Gmail service with Angular 5.  This is a simple Send an Email function

My GAS code is as follows:

```
function doGet(e){
    var addressee = e.parameters.addressee;
    var subject = e. parameters.subject;
    var body = e.parameters.body;
    sendEmailNA(addressee, subject, body);
}
function sendEmailNA(addressee, subject, body) {
    GmailApp.sendEmail(addressee, subject, body);
}
```

My Angular Service:

```
sendGoogleEmailNoAttach(addressee: string, subject: string, body: string){
return this.http.get('https://script.google.com/macros/s/[script ID here]/exec?addressee='+addressee+'&subject='+subject+'&body='+body);
}
```

My Angular Component:

```
sendGoogleEmail(){
    for(var i = 0; i < this.addressees.length; i++){
     this.dataService.sendGoogleEmailNoAttach(this.addressees[i].email, this.message.subject, this.message.body)
    .subscribe((data: any) =>{
        console.log(data);
        this.addressees = [];
        this.message.attachments = [];
   })
   }
}
```

I then publish it as User accessing the web app and Anyone.

I get no error in Stackdriver Logging.  I simply get a CORS error on the local console which to me historically means an error elsewhere.

Any thoughts or ideas is appreciated.  Thank you.

Comment: If for deploying Web Apps, you set "Execute the app as" and "Who has access to the app" as "User accessing the web app" and "Anyone", respectively, each user is required to access to Web Apps using own access token. In your script, it seems that the access token is not used. How about this?

Comment: Typically an Authorization request is generated.  That does not seem to occur in Gmail.  Can you identify I should do this? In GAS or in my local script?

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm really sorry my comment was not useful for your situation.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few possible problems that can be happening here. As I do not have enough reputation to comment and ask for more information, as your answer was asked in 2018 and you might have patched it, I will list it down below.

Getting a CORS error has a few reasons which for you, which could be:

1. Your script ran and returned nothing, though it is unclear whether you have patched it. If your script returned nothing, google script will serve a HTML page saying that the code returned nothing which will trigger a CORS error.
2. Your script has encountered an error, which will also cause google script to return a HTML page and also cause a CORS error.

You can test it using [hurl.it](https://hurl.it) to see what your script returns, and you can test your script inside the google script editor and set it to possible values.

Hope this is not too late!